# PagedList with Entity Framework getting all records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, pagedlist

PagedList is an Paging library.

```
_dbContext.Products.ToList().ToPagedList(1, 25);
```

Above code will get first 25 record in database for Page 1.

The problem is that the `ToList()` call will get all record in the database. Then the `ToPageList()` call will select the first 25 records.

How do I combine EF with PagedList so that I only get the first 25 records in the database? And not get all records, and then take the first 25 record.

PS: Should I write my own Paging library or use an online library? Please suggest me any other library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, you are doing a `ToList()`, so the query will be executed, and deferred execution won't be deferred anymore.

You can try it without the `ToList()` call, but it all depends on the implementation of the `ToPagedList(int, int)` method.

You can just do the paging yourself.

```
const int pageSize = 25;
const int pageNumber = 1;

IQueryable<Product> query = _dbContext.Products;
var pagedQuery = query.Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

And yes, you can just hide this logic behind an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`.

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions {
    public static IQueryable<T> ToPagedQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int pageSize, int pageNumber) {
        return query.Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(pageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but it just misses a `<T>` after the method name: `ToPagedQuery<T>(..)`

Comment: @Maarten. Any ideas on how do you get this to work asynchronously?

Comment: @Thierry Call the async methods? Assuming the Skip and Take are also available async. Otherwise, call them normally but wrap it in a task.

Comment: why if my db context entity is dbquery type and using sql string to get the data?
can you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020780/how-to-implement-pagedlist-on-dbquery-entity-in-dbcontext-without-fetching-full?noredirect=1#comment116728257_66020780

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution is to use `AsEnumerable()` but it requires ordering. Unlike `ToList()`, `AsEnumerable()` doesn't hit the database.

```
_dbContext.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Id).AsEnumerable().ToPagedList(1, 25);
```

Comment: You don't even need this `AsEnumerable()`. You can use directly `_dbContext.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToPagedList(1, 25);`.