# ToPagedList returns all records

Tags: c#, pagedlist

I'm having a problem finding the answer to this question, I have only found 1 other question here [PagedList with Entity Framework getting all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766300/pagedlist-with-entity-framework-getting-all-records) but it never received a reply and I have looked through here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pagedlist.

So my question is the same, does pagedlist return all the records, then skip and take the required number as the default, so for example if the database has 1000 records it will return all records then take say the 1st 10 for page 1 etc.

From my own debugging, it does appear that way, but I'm looking for some clarification.

Thanks

George

-----------------Extra Code -------------------

Hi Maarten

Below is how I have my paging set up:

```
var model = new DisplayMemberForumRepliesViewModel
                    {
                        DisplayMemberForumReplyDetails = _imf.RepliesToForumPost(postId).ToPagedList(page, _numberOfRecordsPerPage)

                    };
```

View Model

```
public class DisplayMemberForumRepliesViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<MembersForumProperties> DisplayMemberForumReplyDetails { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MembersForumProperties> SelectForumPostReplies { get; set; }
}
```

As mentioned earlier, it seems to return all records, then selects the records paged.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong, I'm getting the data from an sql stored procedure which I have added below.

```
SELECT        a.[MemberUsername]                        AS ForumMember,
                  a.[MemberID]                              AS ForumMemberID,
                  a.[MemberAvatarLocation]                  AS ForumMemberAvatar,
                  b.[ForumPostID]                           AS ForumPostID,
                 -- b.[ForumPostReplyID]                        AS ForumPostReplyID,
                  b.[ForumPostReplyMessage]                 AS ForumReplyMessage,
                  b.[ForumPostReplyDateTime]                AS ForumRelyDateTimePosted,
                  b.[ForumPostReplyMessage]                 AS ForumPostReply,
                  c.[ForumPostTitle]                        AS ForumPostTitle
            FROM [WebsiteMembership].[dbo].[tblMemberProfile] a 
       INNER JOIN [Website].[dbo].[tblForumMembersPostReplies] b  ON a.[MemberID]=b.[ForumPostReplyMemberID]
       INNER JOIN [Website].[dbo].[tblForumMembersPost] c  ON a.[MemberID]=c.[ForumMemberID]
       WHERE b.[ForumPostID] = @ForumPostID
      ORDER BY b.[ForumReplyTableID] DESC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I wanted to answer it anyway.

Paged List will query the amount of rows you specified in `pageSize` parameter. The thing is you didn't provide the code implementation for `_imf.RepliesToForumPost(postId)`.

I'd guess your code inside `RepliesToForumPost` is getting all replies for that said post, then doing pagination with `PagedList` after it already got all data from database, which is not what you would want.

Just to clarify, I'm gonna provide two possible implementations as example.

This first one will do a deferred execution of the query (it'll hit database and get all records before paged list):

```
public IEnumerable<MembersForumProperties> RepliesToForumPost(int postId)
{
    using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
    {
        return db.MembersForum.Where(c => c.PostId == postId).ToList();
    }
}
```

Now, this second one just get the `IQueryable<>` to serve as a `query` and paged list is the one which will execute the query to the number of records you wanted.

```
public IQueryable<MembersForumProperties> RepliesToForumPost(int postId)
{
    using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
    {
        return db.MembersForum.Where(c => c.PostId == postId).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Also, you should take note `PagedList` will always execute two methods:

- One call to `Count()` of your `IEnumerable` to recognize the total records ( whether your `IEnumerable` is a materialized list of objects or just the `IQueryable` expression representation)
- Another one to get the desired records (again, whether is from a materialized list or not)

This means if you're working, for example, with **Entity Framework** and using the non-materialized `IEnumerable` (or, the `IQueryable` as my second implementation), Paged List call to `Count()` on the `IEnumerable` will make `Entity Framework` execute a query to retrieve the total number of rows, which could be 1000 (it's a simple `count` in database, it wouldn't get 1000 records at all), and a second call to retrieve your actual records/objects, in respect to `pageSize` you wished (for example, 10 records).

If I had a materialized list which 1000 objects because my code called `ToList()` as my first example, PagedList would still recognize the `IEnumerable` (a list) had 1000 items, and would paginate your 10 records, without executing any queries to database (since your list would be already materialized). Though, your method had returned 1000 rows from database anyway, which is worse than doing two queries (one to get 10 records and a count to recognize the query would return 1000).

Answer (score 0):

No, EF doesn't retrieve all records if correctly queried. Since you don not show the specific implementation of your ToPagedList method, we can't tell.

[Check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19784620/261050) on your mentioned question.